# Why am I getting a KeyError message?

Tags: julia

Every time I call Pkg.Update() I get the following message:

```
KeyError: key "RDataSets" not found
```

I am aware that the correct name of the package is `RDatasets` and not `RDataSets`. When I first tried to install this package I must have made a mistake and entered a capital "S." Actually the package initially did not install and I had to painfully call Pkg.clone() for several packages it depended on.

Is this an indication of a serious problem? Everything seems to be working fine, but I am just starting (again) with Julia, so I am not sure. Also, can this problem be fixed?

Comment: What happens if you `Pkg.rm("RDataSets")`?

Comment: what is the name of the library in your Julia v0.5 library folder (e.g. `~/.julia/v0.5/` on Unix) ?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas - It worked. Now I can do Pkg.update() without seeing the error message. THANKS.

Comment: @KevinLKeys - I have                                                                          `C:\Users\Soldalma\.julia\v0.5\RDatasets\src\RDatasets.jl`